# How can I move a button inside a div out of that div using just CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons inside a div and another button outside the div. I am trying to bring one of the button inside the div to outside below the button sitting outside of the div. See sample code below.

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="Reject">Reject</button>
  <button id="Accept">Accept</button>
</div>
<button id="Manage">Settings</button>
```

In the above example I need to bring the Reject button out of the div and add it below the settings button using CSS. I don't have control over HTML.

I tried positioning and :after hacks but nothing working

Comment: Show us more context, please. What's happening _around_ these elements is relevant.

Comment: You can't change the HTML, you can't change the DOM with CSS. You can make it look like the button is not in the container. How you do that depends on what your buttons and container look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a common parent, you could use `display: contents;`

### display: contents

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes. Please note that the CSS Display Level 3 spec defines how the contents value should affect "unusual elements" — elements that aren't rendered purely by CSS box concepts such as replaced elements.
> [display: contents - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#contents)

Check the support on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents)

```css
.container {
  display: contents;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

#Reject {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <button id="Reject">Reject (first in dom, last on screen)</button>
    <button id="Accept">Accept</button>
  </div>
  <button id="Manage">Settings</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This brings all three buttons to the same common parent, whereas the OP asks for just one button to be brought outside the container.

Comment: Fair enough, I was focused on the phrase "add it below the settings button" and gave a solution to answer it.

Comment: Hi Amaury Hanser, This helped. Thanks for your answer